# Getting an error when checking the JBOSS version

Tags: java, jboss

I am working on upgrading `JBoss` from 7.0.* to 7.0.8. I have not yet started the upgrade when I tried checking g for what version I have installed currently. I got the transport error 202, transport_init 510.

Can someone help me debug this

```
[root@ip-xx-xxx-x-xx bin]# ./standalone.sh -version
```

=========================================================================

```
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss-eap-7.0

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:"/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/log/gc.log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

=========================================================================

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
```

Answer (score 0):

`standalone.sh` actually launches JBoss, which fails because you already have a running instance on the same port.

For JBoss 7 , you may find the version information here (replace *your-jboss-host*, and the port part if your JBoss management port is not 9090 ):

http://your-jboss-host:9090/console/App.html#server-overview

Comment: management console as per standalone.xml is on 9990, can you be more descriptive on how i can resolve this issue,where i dont see that error again?

Comment: Did you manage to access the above url and see the version ? The error you had : "Address already in use" means that you were attempting to launch another JBoss instance on a port not available (since probably another JBoss was already running on that port).Your command line probably would have worked if JBoss wasn't already running.

Comment: Our jboss managment console is set on port 9990 and i used your url like this http://your-jboss-host:9990/console/App.html#server-overview. jboss is up and running, i just need it to show me the correct version of the jboss when i run ./standalone -version command. what do i need to edit to make it work?